# What does it mean $T\alpha_{j}$ is "uniquely expressible"?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the introductory discussion of representation of transformation by matrices, the author points out as follows:

> ... If $T$ is any linear transformation from $V$ into $W$, then $T$ is determined by its action on the vectors $\alpha_{j}$. Each of the $n$ vectors $T\alpha_{j}$ is **uniquely expressible** as a linear combination $$T\alpha_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}A_{ij}\beta_{i}$$ of the $\beta_{i}$, the scalars $A_{1j},\ldots,A_{mj}$ being the coordinates of $T\alpha_{j}$ in the ordered basis $\mathfrak{B'}$...

However, I can't figure out what is the meaning of "uniquely expressible" in this context. Apparently, there is a possibility some of $T\alpha_{j}$ can be the same because a linear transformation is not necessarily one-one, which leads to the conclusion that they may not be unique. Then, what is it that it means?

Comment: Here the $\beta_i$ have to form a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29#Properties).

Comment: @TonyK Then, it talks about the uniqueness of $A$, not of $T\alpha_{j}$. Am I correct?

Comment: Unicity of the expression of $T\alpha_j$ in this basis. That is, the $A_{ij}$'s are uniquely determined by $T\alpha_j$.

Comment: @ClementC. Do you mean to say the uniqueness of expression's' of $T\alpha_{j}$, not of an expression of one of $T\alpha_{j}$? Then, it seems you're right.

Comment: It means that for each $j$ there is a unique sequence $A_{1j},…,A_{mj}$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: I was too obsessed with the uniqueness of $T\alpha_{j}$. All the comments above was trying to say that it is the expression of $T\alpha_{j}$—not $T\alpha_{j}$ itself—that is unique. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there is only one possible value for each scalar $A_{ij}$. (It says nothing about whether the various $A\alpha_j$ are equal or not.)